# How to get the Revisor details?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to take the `Revisor` and `CheckOutUser` user details for the Page. Below is my code

```cs
Page page = engine.GetObject(package.GetValue("Page.ID")) as Page;
string revisor = page.Revisor.Description;
string currentuser = page.CheckOutUser.Description;
```

Currently, the page is updated by the user "A"
and user "B" checkedout the page now. But am getting the `Revisor` and `CheckOutUser` as "B",but the revisor should be "A"

The "page.Revisor.Description" is considering the checkedout version instead of current version.

How to get the correct revisor details?

Comment: Thanks for posting, @user1428019. You might also be interested in the [Area 51 proposal Tridion-specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TOM.NET API documentation states the following for the `VersionedItem.Revisor` Property: *Gets a value indicating the user who last modified this (version of this) item.*

So indeed you would be getting the user who checked out the item at this time rather than the user who last modified it before that.

So if you need to have the previous Revisor, you should open that version of the item, reading it from its history. You can simply use `Session.GetObject(TcmUri)` where you create a new instance of the TcmUri using the previous version: `TcmUri(itemId, itemType, publicationId, version)`

By the way the code example you give is coming from a Template, but you indicate you are using it in a event handler (there is no engine in a event handler). In the Template you would not get this result as that should be using the last checked in version of the item when you Publish it. For Preview you will see the same results as you are now, since that again is working with the current (checked out) version.

Comment: Yes Bart, i know there is no engine in Event handler by mistake i have added that line, am just trying to get the correct information from the templlate,then i will convert that to Event Handler.

Comment: Please note there will be differences in behavior between Template code and an Event Handler, depending on which Phase you are subscribing too. Just as there are differences between Preview and Publish of a Template.

Comment: Thanks Bart. Is there any other way to unit test the event handler code rather than uploading the dll into the server and resetting the IIS? This is affecting the other users who are working in the Tridion CME.

Comment: You can't really unit test event handler code indeed, if you have a development environment this is where you should write your code, having no impact on the authors and editors of the production environment. However you can indeed be in the way of your fellow developers on that server. Testing your code in a Template is not a super bad idea, just be aware that you might encounter some differences in behavior.

Comment: VersionedItem vi = session.GetObject(page.Id) as VersionedItem; String LastUser = vi.Revisor.Description; is this correct Bart? to get the last modifier description.

Comment: I think that should do the trick indeed, optionally you can specifically add the version you want by creating a new instance of the TcmUri as indicated in my answer. However that does mean you need to load the item first to see its version history and then again with the correct version, so check out if your suggestion works.

Answer (score 3):

It is working as you expect if you are reading checked in version of page (i.e. your ID is "tcm:xx-xx-64"). Hovewer if you are reading dynamic version (that is checked out version - "tcm:xx-xx-64-v0") you will get situation when `Revisor` and `CheckOutUser` are the same. The reason for this is that the dynamic version of your page is not the same as checked in version. Dynamic version is only temporary object where all the actions were done by user who checked out the item, so `Revisor` and `CheckOutUser` for this version of page is the user who checked it out.

Comment: I believe we also use "minor" versions to refer to these dynamic, intermediate updates.

Comment: @AlvinReyes Not really, minor version refer to "1.3", "2.6" and so on, it is only visible to check-out user. Dynamic version - is idemId-v0. This is autoamtically the latest minor version. Other users can see if there's dynamic version, but the can't see if it's "2.1" or "2.6", for example